# Update table with temp table only when values are different in the same columns

Tags: sql, database, import

I want to update a table with contact data with data of a temporary table. Because there
are a big amount of rows i have to update i just want the columns to be updated that have different values than the columns in the temporary table. (In the main table should only be the values be updated for the columns that also exist in the temporary table)
The columns of the both tables can be assigned to each other with a personID.

I tried to update each column individually like this:

```
UPDATE tblContact 
SET tblContact.Lastname = t.Lastname
FROM tblContact c
INNER JOIN #TestTable t
ON c.PersNbr = t.PersNbr
WHERE c.Lastname != t.Lastname
```

To do this for every column isnt very performant. So do u know any possibility to check in an update statement if the value of two columns are different and only if the columns are different update the column in my main table? Or maybe a way to combine all my update statements for every column like the one aboth into one statement?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server as RDBMS. Following are diagrams of my two tables:

[image: TempTable]

[image: tblContacts (Main table)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the columns:

```
UPDATE c 
    SET c.Lastname = t.Lastname,
        c.Firstname = t.Firstname,
        . . . 
FROM tblContact c INNER JOIN
     #TestTable t
     ON c.PersNbr = t.PersNbr
WHERE c.Lastname <> t.Lastname OR
      c.Firstname <> t.Firstname OR
      . . .;
```

If you expect a change in at least one column, then you don't really need the `WHERE` clause.  However, it is more efficient in SQL Server if you avoid unnecessary updates where no values change.

Comment: Hi Gordon I'm using your example but my problem atm is that it always inflicts every entry in tblContact. I will post my statement below

Comment: @LosDichtos . . . I don't understand your comment.  What does "inflict" mean?

Comment: I'm adding the columns like in the statement in the answer below. When i execute this statement all entries in tblContacts got updatet not only the entries which can be joined and are different to the values in #TestTable

Comment: I found the problem. I did a mistake in my statement

Answer (score 0):

You could combine all columns into a single string of text, and then perform an MD5 hash on them to detect any differences between all columns simultaneously. This negates the use the OR logic which is exceedingly slow. This is far better for On Prem databases than Cloud-based deployments, but it is fast and simple.

```
UPDATE C SET 
    C.FirstName = T.FirstName,
    C.LastName = T.Lastname
FROM tblContact C
JOIN #TestTable T
    ON T.PersNbr = C.PersNbr
WHERE 
    HASHBYTES('MD5',C.FirstName + C.LastName + C.Title) 
    != HASHBYTES('MD5',T.FirstName + T.LastName + T.Title)
```